# Where can I find a good mwclient introduction?

Tags: python, wiki, mediawiki

I'm just starting with [mwclient](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mwclient/). I'm going to create bots to query our MediaWiki database and make small revisions.

But I cannot find anywhere a simple list of python commands like how to get ages of pages, contents of categories, contents of pages, etc.

Does anyone know a good *starters* resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my colleagues just sent me a link to the [MediaWiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) wiki page.

Comment: I've been playing with `mwclient` for some weeks now and, weirdly, this is a pretty good advice — maybe I'm missing some python documentation command, but `help()` only shows the defaults, the API page shows all the possible values.

Answer (score 3):

The official docs at https://github.com/mwclient/mwclient/wiki have some introductory tutorials. I'm in charge for documentation for mwclient but haven't had enough time to really expand them - could use help from anyone who is willing.

Answer (score 1):

I currently use python+urllib for API queries, and mwclient whenever I need to edit/create a page.

An useful place to get started with mwclient (read/edit/create a page):

http://brianna.modernthings.org/article/134/write-api-enabled-on-wikimedia-sites

Answer (score 0):

The [Bot Manual](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Bot) also has tons of good info and links, e.g. [creating a bot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aCreating_a_bot).